# Unable to obtain output in the form of a summation expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, summation, expression-manipulation

The following code returns a series expressed with a summation symbol$\sum$:

```
expr = -t^Range[0, 5] // Total

to\[CapitalSigma][expr_Plus] := 
 Block[{n}, 
  HoldForm[Sum[#, {n, #2}]] & @@ {FindSequenceFunction[List @@ expr, 
     n], Length@expr}]

to\[CapitalSigma]@expr
```

Out[1]: $-1 - t - t^2 - t^3 - t^4 - t^5$

Out[2]: $\sum_n^6 -t^{-1+n}$

So I tried to use it to obtain a summation expression for $\frac{1}{1-y}$:

```
expr = Series[1/(1 - y), {y, 0, 5}]
to\[CapitalSigma][expr_Plus] := 
 Block[{n}, 
  HoldForm[Sum[#, {n, #2}]] & @@ {FindSequenceFunction[List @@ expr, 
     n], Length@expr}]

to\[CapitalSigma]@expr
```

But I received the following output:

Out[1]: $1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5+O[y]^6$

Out[2]: $\text{to}\sum[1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5+O[y]^6]$

I don't want this expanded form $1+y+y^2+\dots$. How can I make Mathematica provide the proper summation expression which would be something like:
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty y^j$$

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to "normalize" the output of the Series[ ] command to drop the Higher Order Terms expression, and it works.

```
    expr = Series[1/(1 - y), {y, 0, 5}] //Normal

    1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5
```

then running

```
    to\[CapitalSigma]@expr
```

gave me

[image]

Comment: Ok great! I just tried on another function though ant it doesn't work for this one - `f[z_] := Log[y - z] Series[f[z], {z, 0, 3}]  // Normal
to\[CapitalSigma]@expr` - Any idea why it doesn't work for this one?

Comment: when it expands the `Log[y-z]` into a series, the series is... `Log[y] - z/y - z^2/(2 y^2) - z^3/(3 y^3)` so you'd need a way to strip off that `Log[y]`.

Comment: How do I do that?..I am essentially a total newcomer to Mathematica so alot of basic stuff is still awkward for me.

Comment: ..sign and now the `to\[CapitalSigma]@expr` has stopped working. God this is painful.